# How to post message to Facebook wall from the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am new to iPhone. My application connects to Facebook using the iPhone SDK, and I can post a default message using

> @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php/?message=Hello"

but in my application all messages display on tableview and I want to post the selected message on the wall of Facebook, store selected message in a Twitter message (variable `twittermessage`) and write

> @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php/?message=%@",twittermessage;

But it gives the following error.

> statically instance of Objective-C
>   NSString

I used the iPhone Facebook SDk from *[How To Post on Facebook with your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app)*.

Comment: you are using that example right?? that example is working properly. Now compare your project with that example and findout whats wrong with your code :)

Comment: ya i am using that sdk and am able to connect to facebook and able to post message but i can't display tableview selected message on wall default.

Comment: what is this term doing in your example ?? `twittermessage`

Comment: declare NSString as twittermessage because in my app i displayed all messages on tableview access throgh fromdatabase using web services and provide share message in twitter & facebook suppose we select first,second, or other message on tableview when select that message displayed a popup message ie facebook,twitter and report abuse options i want to share that message in twitteror facebook at that time i daclare twittermessage as nsstring select message assign to that string and attach to twitter and facebook urls.

Comment: Hello Sirisha, I hope my ans is true for your quest, then you can accept my ans as a true ans by clicking on checkbox of my ans. Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

the error message you are getting is due to NSString. this is not an facebook error.

In order to post a message on facebook use the following code

```
[NSString stringwithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php/?message=%@",twittermessage];
```

Then use this string as a reference for the URL to post a message